# How to add 'n' literal control to a view in asp.net MVC5 dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and have a basic understanding of it.

I have to add a literal control in view.cshtml dynamically for n times through code(using c#).
In aspx.cs we can perform like this,

```
        string[] url= SingleSignOnManager.SignOut();
        foreach (var obj in url)
        {
          this.LogoutPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<p><a href='{0}'></a>&nbsp;<img width='1px' src='{0}?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0' " + "title='Signout request: {0}?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0'/></p>", obj)));                                                                    
        }
```

I doubt whether literal is available in MVC or  not.How to do this same in a mvc view and controller?

EDIT: I created a model class Url, added code in controller and view.

Model - Url.cs

```
public class Url
{
    public string[] signedInUrls { get; set; }
}
```

Controller - ReedController.cs

```
.
.
.
url = new Url()
{
     signedInUrls = SingleSignOnManager.SignOut()
};
```

View : sample.cshtml

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <div id="main">      
            <div id="Panel">   

                 @model AppOne.Models.Url  

                foreach (string url in Models.Url)
                {
                  <p><a href='@url'></a>&nbsp;<img width='1px' src='@url?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0' "+" title='Signout request: @url?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0' /></p>
                }

            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

In View, inside foreach loop, i am getting error:

> The name 'url' doesnot exist in the current context.

Comment: Pass a `List<string>` model to the view and then in the view use a loop to generate the html - `@foreach (string url in Model) { <p><a href="@Model"></a> ..... }`

Comment: For starters you dont have elements like `<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" />` in cshtml at its razor and not forms. You need to work the pattern by reloading partials and generate it there. or dynamically generate the html it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen suggested, you should Add a `List<string>` property to your model and use it in view:

```
@foreach(string s in Model.YourList){
    <p>
    Your text here...use the string like: @s whenever required
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.I added the foreach in view.cshtml, but then intelisense doesn't show up and @s throws error-saying the name doesnot exist in the current context.

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I got it.Thanks :)